# How to put a widget in a certain cell of a grid?

Tags: c, linux, gtk, gtk3

Any time I try to attach a widget to a grid, it only attaches to the 0, 0 coordinates no matter which coordinates i specify.

What I mean is that
`gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), label1, 0, 0, 1, 1)`
and
`gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), label1, 1, 1, 1, 1)`
return the same result - the label is in the upper left corner of the window.

If I place one widget at 0, 0, coordinates, then I can not put the second widget further than the edge of the fist one:
`gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), label2, 1, 1, 1, 1)` or `gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID grid, label2, 2, 1, 1, 1)`
both get the second label right next to the first.
`GTK_GRID_INSERT_COLUMN` does not change anything.

Comment: [Does this Help](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLN_MPJUQgPVpNTZk3PIi-Z5SiFNeUyj6Z)?

Answer (score 0):

If you do `gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), label1, 1, 1, 1, 1)`, then the widget is certainly attached at (1, 1), but if there are no other widgets in the grid then row 0 will have zero height, and column 0 will have zero width, so visually the effect is the same as if you had attached it at (0, 0).

You'll have to put widgets somewhere in column 0 or row 0 so that they aren't zero width or height anymore.

Or, if it fits with the UI you are trying to build, set the grid to be homogeneous so that all cells are the same size.

Alternatively, if you are just trying to make sure the label is not positioned next to the very edge of the grid, don't use (1, 1) for that. Instead, attach it at (0, 0) and change the `margin-start`/`margin-top` properties of the label, or change the `border-width` property of the grid.